# How do I change the case of all dataframes in list in R

Tags: r

Say I have a list with multiple dataframes. I would like to change the column names to lower case in all dataframes. How do I do it.

Say if my list is `lst1`, I tried `lapply(lst1, function(x){colnames(x) <- tolower(colnames(x))})`.

Answer (score 2):

We need to return the dataset or else it returns only the column names which is the last assigned output

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x){
       colnames(x) <- tolower(colnames(x))
         x})
```

---

Or another option is to use `setNames`

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) setNames(x, tolower(names(x))))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
              rename_all(~ tolower(.)))
```

NOTE: It is always good to specify `colnames` instead of `names` as `names` can be different for a `matrix`.  But `colnames` work for both

NOTE2: `return` is not really needed in `R`

Answer (score 0):

It can also be used `names()` and `return()`. Here an example:

```
#Data
list1 <- list(iris,mtcars)
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {names(x)<-toupper(names(x));return(x)})
lapply(list1,names)
```

So our input names look like:

```
[[1]]
[1] "SEPAL.LENGTH" "SEPAL.WIDTH"  "PETAL.LENGTH" "PETAL.WIDTH"  "SPECIES"     

[[2]]
 [1] "MPG"  "CYL"  "DISP" "HP"   "DRAT" "WT"   "QSEC" "VS"   "AM"   "GEAR" "CARB"
```

Now the code:

```
#Code
list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x){names(x) <- tolower(names(x));return(x)})
lapply(list2,names)
```

How the names will look now:

```
[[1]]
[1] "sepal.length" "sepal.width"  "petal.length" "petal.width"  "species"     

[[2]]
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```